# Different platform AppDomains in one .Net process?

Tags: .net, dll, x86, 64-bit, appdomain

I am interesting in: can i load 32bit x86 dll as a second AppDomain into 64 bit application environment?

For more details:

1) Main exe is 64 bit C# pure .net 4 app;

2) Module is third party .net 2.0 wrapper of some unmanaged x86 dll;

So can i create second 32bit AppDomain in 64bit .net 4 process and load 32bit module into new created 32bit AppDomain? And then marshal between default 64bit AppDomain and second 32bit AppDomain?

Thank you for any advice!

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: Exception System.BadImageFormatException occurs in kernelbase.dll ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's not possible, bitness is a process property, not an appdomain property.  To make this work, you'll need to load that DLL in a separate process.  Use the standard .NET IPC mechanisms to talk to it.  Named pipes, sockets, remoting, WCF.  Or force the Platform target setting to x86.